# VBA: Linking Visual Studio Code to Excel Input Cells & Output Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio

For a web scraping project, I am planning to send requests through a specific port. For this purpose, I have to use Microsoft Visual Studio as the Excel VBA console does not support such features.

The respective weblinks shall, however, be directly sourced from a Microsoft Excel table. Also, the results of the web scraping should ideally feed into the same Excel table. Is there any way to link Visual Studio with a specific sheet for such a purpose?

I have, thus far, found responses on the use of VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) add-ins for Excel but could not really spot a way to apply such add-in tools. Please find below the code I am using, which is working well in Visual Studio but lacks the link to Excel, as mentioned.

```
Imports System.Net

Class Client
Inherits WebClient
Const username As String = "[USERNAME]"
Const password As String = "[PASSWORD]"
Const port = 22225
Public session_id As String = New Random().Next().ToString()

Public Sub New(Optional country As String = Nothing)
    Me.Proxy = New WebProxy("[PROXY]", port)
    Dim login = username &
        If(country IsNot Nothing, "-country-" & country, "") &
        "-session-" & session_id
    Me.Proxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(login, password)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(address As Uri) As WebRequest
    Dim request = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
    request.ConnectionGroupName = session_id
    Return request
End Function
End Class


Module TermFinder
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Performing request(s)")
    Dim session As New Client()

    Dim x%, sheet As Variant
    For x = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Sheets.Count
    Set sheet = Sheets(x)

Next

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 8 To 772

        url = "[Links to be covered]"

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
Set var1 = html.getElementById("resultStats")
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
            Cells(i, 7).Value = var1.innerText
        Else : Cells(i, 7).Value = "0 results"

        End If

        DoEvents

    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the Office/SharePoint function as part of the Visual Studio program.
2. On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.
3. In the templates pane, expand Visual Basic, and then expand Office/SharePoint.
4. Under the expanded Office/SharePoint node, select the Office Add-ins node.
5. In the list of project templates, select Excel Add-in or Open Excel Workbook.

=> That way you should be able to use a full Excel workbook in Visual Studio.